# How do I filter by date in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

I'm trying to filter by date in a SQL query as follows.

```
select *
from table_name 
where date_col="2015-04-02"
limit 5
```

I'm getting an error as follows.

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
select *
from table_name
where date_col="2015-04-02"
limit 5
': column "2015-04-02" does not exist
LINE 4: where date_col="2015-04-02"
```

Date 2015-04-02 exists in the database. What am I missing here?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: use single quotes......  '2015-04-02'

Comment: Use single quote, like `where date_col = '2015-04-02' `

Comment: Try using single quotes. @NAS_2339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use single quotes in `where` clause, double quotes are used in column identifier or reserved words.

```
select *
from table_name
where date_col = '2015-04-02'
limit 5
```